# Is it possible to render subscript and superscript in ActiveAdmin pages?

Tags: activeadmin

I am trying to render values and labels for rows on show and index pages using subscript and superscript. I tried adding the actual html to do like `<sub>2</sub>` but it just shows the raw html tags and does not render the results of that tag as expected.

Also is it possible to have subscript and superscript in a form select input for the new and edit pages as well?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible:

```
column(:foo) do |object|
  "<sub>#{object.foo}</sub>".html_safe
end
```